# How to update complex recyclerview item parameters?

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

here is my post item:

```
    public class PostItems {

    private String id_wall_post, id_user, text_wall_post, ..........;

    public PostItems(String id_wall_post, String id_user, String text_wall_post, ..............) {
        this.id_wall_post = id_wall_post;
        this.id_user = id_user;
        this.text_wall_post = text_wall_post;
    }

    String get_id_wall_post() {
        return id_wall_post;
    }

    String get_id_user() {
        return id_user;
    }

    String get_text_wall_post() {
        return text_wall_post;
    }
    ...
    ...
    .........
    ...
    ...
}
```

Here my adapter:

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

    private List<PostItems> postList;
    private Context context;

    PostAdapter(List<PostItems> postList, Context context) {
        this.postList = postList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_wall_post, parent, false);
        return new PostViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PostItems post_items = postList.get(position);
             ...
             ...
             .........
             ...
             ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postList.size();
    }

    static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Using retrofit the recyclerview is populated correctly:

```
postList.addAll(response.body());
  postAdapter = new PostAdapter(postList, ProfileActivity.this);
  recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
```

I also have an Editext where user can update the value of **text_wall_post**; I want now to update the item parameter **text_wall_post** of the recyclerView ?

How could I update a recyclerView item specific parameter ?

**EDIT:**
I have found that:

> 

```
postList.set(1, new PostItems("1","1176", "some text update here", ..................));
postAdapter.notifyItemChanged(1);
```

**In my recyclerView, I have more than 20 parameters.**

Which work but I want a more clean way to update only the needed parameter without updating all the parameters.

Thanks for Any help.

Comment: I am not sure about your question but it seems like the `recyclerview` is actually empty, because you didn't set an value to any item.

Comment: @ First dev the recyclerview is not empty, it is populated after retrofit query success

Comment: try updating `text_wall_pos` in `postList` at specific position and then call `postAdapter.notifyItemChanged (position)`

Comment: **try updating text_wall_pos in postList**, how ? I don't know how to do it's why I'm here for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change an item without creating a new one.
First make setters (like the getters you made) to change a specific parameter from an object(`postItems` in this case)

```
    public class PostItems {

private String id_wall_post, id_user, text_wall_post, ..........;

public PostItems(String id_wall_post, String id_user, String text_wall_post, ..............) {
    this.id_wall_post = id_wall_post;
    this.id_user = id_user;
    this.text_wall_post = text_wall_post;
}

String get_id_wall_post() {
    return id_wall_post;
}

String get_id_user() {
    return id_user;
}

String get_text_wall_post() {
    return text_wall_post;
}

public void setIdWallPost(String idWallpost){
    this.id_wall_post = idWallpost;
}
public void setIdUser(String idUser){
    this.id_user = idWallUser;
}
public void setTextWallPost(String textWallPost){
    this.text_wall_post = textWallPost;
}
...
...
.........
...
...
}
```

You can also make android studio generate them for you by pressing `Alt+Inser` > `Setter`

Then get the item with specific position from `postList` and update the parameter you want

```
postList.get(position).setTextWallPost("new value here");
```

And finally call

```
postAdapter.notifyItemChanged (position)
```